# NOT able to establish a application endpoint in UCMA

Tags: ucma

I am trying to develop an UCMA application with auto provisioning.

I have created necessary trusted pool, trusted application endpoint and added required certificate.

Replication was successful for my trusted pool.

Collaboration platform started successfully and endpoint got discovered.

Then I have called_appEndpoint.BeginEstablish(EndEndpointEstablish, _appEndpoint); when my endpoint got discovered.

Here I am stuck.

The callback EndEndpointEstablish is not being called at all.

I observed in "Endpoint_StateChanged" event that endpoint state is change from 'Idle' to 'Establishing' only. After this state is not at all changed.

I made firewall off in my machine.

But still EndEndpointEstablish is not called and there is no exception also.

Any help please?

Thanks

Sairam

Comment: I suspect a problem in setting up the endpoint properly before trying to establish. Is there any chance of seeing the code, ideally from the creation of the ApplicationEndpointSettings through to your endpoint.BeginEstablish() call?

Comment: Thanks for responding Paul Hodgson.
I am trying to run sample application which comes with UCMA 4.0 SDK.(..\Microsoft UCMA 4.0\SDK\Core\Sample Applications\QuickStarts\AutoProvisioning).
I haven't modified any code except endpoint name in app.config file.

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem? You said _"I have created necessary trusted pool, trusted application endpoint and added required certificate."_ did you create the Trusted Application also on the Lync Management Shell using command `New-CsTrustedApplication -ApplicationId - TrustedApplicationPoolFqdn - Port`

Comment: I could solve it. The problem was name of the FQDN of the trusted application pool. This name had mismatch with our DNS machine host name. So all requests were going to DNS machine instead of Lync server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, your problem could be using the end point name, you should use Trusted Application name.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the certificate to the 'current user' store *and* the 'local computer' store?  For some reason it seems to need to be in both places. When in the 'current user' store only you will notice that the standard Skype/Lync client will work fine but the UCMA client will not.